# Collect string values and add into array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am writing an app where I want to collect names and phone numbers from a list and add them into an array. How do I do this? I could retrieve first name and last name, but I don't get how to add a phone number in the below code as it is in a different **`for` loop**. It might look simple but I am stuck as I am new.

```
for (i = 0; i < [list count]; i++)
{
    NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

    NSString *lastName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

    NSMutableArray *name = [NSMutableArray array];
    if(firstName != nil)
        [name addObject:firstName];

    if(lastName != nil)
        [name addObject:lastName];*/

    [self displaynames:name];


    ABMultiValueRef mobile=ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    for (int k=0;k<ABMultiValueGetCount(mobile); k++)
    {
        NSString *mobileNo = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(mobile, k);
        NSLog(@"mobile number: %@",mobileNo);    
    }
}

- (void)displaynames:(NSMutableArray*)names
{
    for (NSMutableArray* name in names)
    {
        NSLog(@"MyResult:%@ %@",[names objectAtIndex:0],[names objectAtIndex:1]);
    }
}
```

So in the above code I am able to get the first name and last name from the list and add them into the array, similarly how do I get mobile phone number and add into the same array and get the result in the `displayNames:` function as it is another `for` loop. Can someone please edit the code and tell me what changes I have to make in the above code. Also in the result everything is being displayed twice why so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *contactList=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {

    NSMutableDictionary *contactInfo=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [list count]; i++)
    {
        NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        NSString *lastName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

        if (![firstName isEqualToString:@""]) {
            [contactInfo setValue:firstName forKey:@"firstName"];
        }

        if (![lastName isEqualToString:@""]) {
            [contactInfo setValue:lastName forKey:@"lastName"];
        }

        NSMutableArray *mobileNoArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:ABMultiValueGetCount(mobile)];

        ABMultiValueRef mobile=ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

        for (int k=0;k<ABMultiValueGetCount(mobile); k++)
        {
            NSString *mobileNo = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(mobile, k);
            [mobileNoArray addObject:mobileNo];
        }

        if (mobileNoArray.count!=0) {
            [contactInfo setObject:mobileNoArray forKey:@"mobileNo"]
        }
    }

    [contactList addObject:contactInfo];
    NSLog(@"contact info ==  %@",contactInfo);
}

NSLog(@"contact list array is %@",contactList);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...it works but it displays only one list if i want to to show complete list what changes i shd do in above code of urs??

Comment: as you got kABPersonFirstNameProperty ,just add others to dictionary like it.

Comment: When i check contactInfo only one  Firstname lastname and phonenumber of one person remaining its not displayin..if i have 4 contacts i want to display all of them..so whats changes u do in ur above code.

Comment: if you have four contacts then place my code inside loop running to count of contacts

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add the user info in a dictionary or create a model user object and store in the array. So all the information stays encapsulated in a single object.

```
self.users = [NSMutableArray array];
for (i = 0; i < [list count]; i++)
{
        NSString *firstName = ...

        NSString *lastName = ...

        NSString *mobileNumber = ...

        NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        if(firstName)
            userInfo[@"FirstName"] = firstName;
        if(lastName)
            userInfo[@"LastName"] = lastName;
        if(mobileNumber)
            userInfo[@"MobileNumber"] = mobileNumber;

        [self.users addObject:userInfo];

    }
```

You can enumerate using

```
[self.users enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary * userInfo, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        NSString *firstName = userInfo[@"FirstName"];
        NSString *mobileNumber = userInfo[@"MobileNumber"];

    }];
```

Searching for a single user for a name

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"FirstName == %@",@"aUserName"];
NSDictionary *userInfo = [[self.users filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]lastObject];
```

Comment: So above method is not right??i want this way because i want to send the result Data to some other functionality..So can you please  edit the code and i am new to ios..

Comment: so if i want to use userinfo outside this function for further functionality how do i use this??bcoz i  need to send all this data  in peer to peer session thats why.Mobile number is in different for loop in the above code.Also what is users in the above code.

Comment: You can see that all info is added in a property array. If you want to display in a serial way you can do enumeration. If you want to access a specific info, you can filter using `NSPredicate`.

Comment: I have edited the code above can you please check and tell me right and what else i should change.What is self.users ?

Comment: @user2454248 users is a NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 1):

So, instead using `Array` you have to use `Dictionary` to store `FirstName, LastName and MobileNo` with `keyvalue` Pair. If you have multiple user than use `Array` as upper layer, means add your user dictionary into array and when ever you want a user write the code:

```
for(NSDictionary *userDic in yourArray)
{
    NSString *fName = [userDic valueForKey:@"FirstName"];
    ...
}
```

This is one of the way...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

```
NSMutableArray *firstNames;
NSMutableArray *LastNames;
NSMutableArray *Mobile_numbers;
NSMutableArray *type_array;
NSMutableArray *firstandlast;
```

........

```
-(void)get_arr
{
 ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    NSArray *arrayOfPeople = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);    
    NSUInteger index = 0;
    firstNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   Mobile_numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    type_array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init ];
    LastNames=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init ];
   NSMutableArray *firstandlast;

   @try
    {
        for(index = 0; index<=([arrayOfPeople count]-1); index++)
        {

            ABRecordRef currentPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)[arrayOfPeople objectAtIndex:index];

            NSString *type;

            ABMultiValueRef phones = (ABMultiValueRef)ABRecordCopyValue(currentPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

            for (int i=0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); i++)
            {

                //NSString *phone = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i);
                ////NSLog(@"%@", phone);
                mobileLabel = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, i);


                //NSLog(@"MOG:%@",mobileLabel);


                if([mobileLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Mobile>!$_"]||[mobileLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Main>!$_"])
                {
                    //NSLog(@"mobile:");
                    type=@"mobile";
                }
                else if ([mobileLabel  isEqualToString:@"_$!<Work>!$_"])
                {
                    //NSLog(@"Work:");
                    type=@"Work";
                }
                else if ([mobileLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Home>!$_"])
                {
                    //NSLog(@"Home:");
                    type=@"Home";
                }

                else if ([mobileLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Other>!$_"] )
                {
                    //NSLog(@"Other:");
                    type=@"Other";
                }


                mobile = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i);

                //NSLog(@"GG:%@",mobile);


                mobile = [mobile stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-"
                                                                             withString:@""];

                mobile = [mobile stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"("
                                                                             withString:@""];

                mobile = [mobile stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")"
                                                                             withString:@""];

                mobile = [mobile stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "
                                                                             withString:@""];

                [Mobile_numbers addObject:mobile];
                [type_array addObject:type];

                NSString *currentFirstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(currentPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

                ////NSLog(@"NAME:%@",currentFirstName);

                if ([currentFirstName length]!=0)
                {
                    //NSLog(@"NAME:%@",currentFirstName);
                    [firstNames addObject:currentFirstName];
                }
                else
                {
                    //NSLog(@"NAME:DUMMY");
                    currentFirstName=@"";
                    [firstNames addObject:currentFirstName];
                }

                NSString *currentLast = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(currentPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

                ////NSLog(@"NAME:%@",currentFirstName);

                if ([currentLast length]!=0)
                {
                    //NSLog(@"NAME:%@",currentLast);
                    [LastNames addObject:currentLast];
                }
                else
                {
                    //NSLog(@"NAME:DUMMY");
                    currentLast=@"";
                    [LastNames addObject:currentLast];
                }


                   NSString *temp_f_l=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",currentFirstName,currentLast];
                [firstandlast addObject:temp_f_l];
            }


            NSLog(@"MOB:%@",Mobile_numbers);
            NSLog(@"TYPE:%@",type_array);



            NSLog(@"FN:%@",firstNames);
            NSLog(@"FN:%@",LastNames);


             NSLog(@"FN&LN:%@",firstandlast);

        }

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        //NSLog(@"CATCH");


    }

}
```

In my Application. I am using this code to store Addressbook contents to Array. I hope it help for you.

Comment: i want to collect all firstname,lastname and mobile number from the list and send it using peer session so how do i collect all firstname and lastname mobile number

Comment: My code note First name,last name and mobile numbers array. Try this code in your application and check with NSLog it must help.

Comment: No its not..Lot of errors i am facing again i need to change complete code.